# python regulars, compiling and matching

Tags: python, regex

I need to find all strings in a word that match the regex. And I need to compile it first and then print the words, this is what I done:

```
prog = re.compile(pattern)
result = prog.match(string)
for i in result:
    print i
```

it raises error. What should I change ?

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: Please provide some sample data, input/output and the error you are getting.

Comment: "I need to compile it first" - you don't. re module does that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SRE_Match` returned by `match` function is not iterable. You might have wanted to iterate over the list of all the matched items. In that case, you have to use `findall` function like this

```
result = prog.findall(string)
```

For example,

```
import re
prog = re.compile("([a-z])")
result = prog.findall("a b c")
for i in result:
    print i
```

**Output**

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1):

The method .match does not return directly the strings of the match, but a so called match object.

Something like that.

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0041FC80>
```

What you want to do is following:

```
prog = re.compile(pattern)
matches = prog.findall(string)
for i in matches():
    print i
```